# php undefined index error

Tags: php

I have a stored procedure with three parameters @startdate, @enddate and @field1 and when I try to execute the following php code, I get error

**undefined index: startdate
undefined index: enddate
undefined index: field1**

```
<?php
$myServer = "instance_name"; // host/instance_name
$myUser = "username"; // username
$myPass = "password"; // paasword
$myDB = "databasename"; // database name
$dbhandle = mssql_connect($myServer, $myUser, $myPass)
or die("Couldn’t connect to SQL Server on $myServer");
$selected = mssql_select_db($myDB, $dbhandle)
or die("Couldn’t open database $myDB");

<?php
$startdate = isset($_REQUEST['startdate']) ? $_REQUEST['startdate'] : null;
$enddate = isset($_REQUEST['enddate']) ? $_REQUEST['enddate'] : null;
$field1 = isset($_REQUEST['field1']) ? $_REQUEST['field1'] : null;
?>

<form action = "thisfile.php" method = "post">
Please input startdate <input type = "text" name = "startdate" /> </br>
Please input enddate <input type = "text" name = "enddate" /> </br>
Please input field1 name <input type = "text" name = "field1" /> </br>
Please submit <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit" /> </br>
</form>

<table border = "5" id="1">

 <?php
    if (isset($startdate) && isset($enddate) ){
$query = "storedprocedure '$startdate','$enddate','field1'";
    $result = mssql_query($query);
while ($rows = mssql_fetch_array($result) ) {
echo "<tr><td>".$rows[0]."&nbsp;<td>".$rows[1]."&nbsp;
   <td>".$rows[2]."&nbsp;<td>".$rows[3]."&nbsp;
    <td>".$rows[4]."&nbsp;<td>".$rows[5]."&nbsp;";
}
}

</table>
</body>
</html>
```

I was just looking for three text boxes on the top and when I enter startdate, enddate and field1 names in the text boxes, it should display the output in the same page.

Edit:
My stored procedure is something similar to below :

```
Create procedure storedprocedure
@startdate datetime,
@enddate datetime,
@field1  varchar(50)
select date, sum(qty), sum(qty), sum(qty2), sum(qty3), sum(qty4) from table1
where date between @startdate and @enddate and field1 like @field1 + '%'
group by date
```

Comment: Are you sure that your `$_REQUEST` has an `enddate` and `field1` elements?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

why don't you do try this

```
if (isset($startdate) && isset($enddate) ){
$query = "storedprocedure '$startdate','$enddate','field1'";
    $result = mssql_query($query);
while ($rows = mssql_fetch_array($result) ) {
echo "<tr><td>".$rows[0]."&nbsp;<td align=right>".$rows[1]."&nbsp;
   <td align=right>".$rows[2]."&nbsp;<td align=right>".$rows[3]."&nbsp;
    <td align=right>".$rows[4]."&nbsp;<td align=right>".$rows[5]."&nbsp;";
}
}
```

This should stop  the notice

Comment: I edited the code as above(in my question) but still it displays nothing. Now it doesn't show any error but doesn't fetch any data also from database. Only the three text boxes are there.

Comment: Before the if statement, try to echo out $startdate and $enddate to see if it is set

Comment: Yes I checked echo out for $startdate, $enddate and $field1...of course it is set...it prints startdate, enddate and field1 input values correctly but cannot fetch any rows for the parameters

Comment: you can also do a var_dump of $rows before looping cos the parameter might not be picking anything from your database

Comment: I have finally found the cause of the issue but I cannot solve it myself. It is field1 which was causing problem. When I removed field1 from parameter and put static value for it. The page could fetch results for startdate and enddate. I updated my original stored procedure in the question. Is there any issue with `like @field1 + '%'`

Comment: Yes..I'm going to mark this as solved...but can you let me know whether the use of `like @field1 + '%'` is correct or not and why if I use this, it cannot fetch results.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15525/discussion-between-omoabobade-and-user1449596)

Answer (score 0):

You can rewrite part of your code in such way:

```
<?php
    $startdate = isset($_REQUEST['startdate']) ? $_REQUEST['startdate'] : null;
    $enddate = isset($_REQUEST['enddate']) ? $_REQUEST['enddate'] : null;
    $field1 = isset($_REQUEST['field1']) ? $_REQUEST['field1'] : null;
?>
```

But actually you need to check whether all your request parameters (especially `enddate` and `field1`) are present.

See also http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php